# How can I delay the evaluation of variables (lazy evaluation)?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, variable

For example, I create 32768 directories named 0,1,2,...32767.

I want to randomly choose one as the path every time I run a command.

So I change `$PATH` to `$PATH:/blabla/$RANDOM`, but it won't work because `$RANDOM` is evaluated immediately.

How can I delay the evaluation?

Comment: Store the actual `PATH` into a `PATHTEMP`. `export` the `PATH` just before executing your command as `export PATH=$PATHTEMP:/blabla/$RANDOM`.

Comment: @Neuron looking for an automatic solution

Comment: Can you paste your script & the expected behaviour ?

Comment: @Neuron I was just wondering if this is possible. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Shells don't do "lazy evaluation", period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a capability of any of the common shells.

Recent versions of [ATT ksh](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/) have a unique feature among shells called discipline functions. You can execute custom code when a variable is accessed, and if you set `.sh.value` to a different value, that value is used instead of the value of the variable.

```
function PATH.get { .sh.value=$PATH:/blabla/$RANDOM; }
```

However even this feature won't help you for `PATH` since it only triggers when a variable is used by the script, not by internal uses of `PATH` inside the shell.

If you want that for the last PATH element, and you're using bash or zsh, you can use their command-not-found feature to invoke custom code if a command is not found. In bash:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
  command "/blabla/$RANDOM/$@"
}
```

In zsh:

```
command_not_found_handler () {
  /blabla/$RANDOM/$1 "$@[2,$#]"
}
```

Apart from these cases, there's no shell feature that'll help you. In any case, no shell feature will help you for programs that are not invoked by a shell.

You could use [`LD_PRELOAD`](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/) to override the [`execlp`, `execvp` and `execvpe`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) library functions to do something different from breaking up `PATH` into colon-separated pieces and interpreting each of them as a directory. See
[Redirect a file descriptor before execution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211394/redirect-a-file-descriptor-before-execution/211459#211459) for an `LD_PRELOAD` example.

Alternatively, you could put a PATH entry on a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem that implements a stacked filesystem that makes the given path correspond to a variable underlying directory. This will work for programs that just call `execve` with each PATH element until one works, but it'll confuse programs that first traverse the PATH entries looking for existing, executable files and then execute the one that is found.