# How to spoof uname -rs per process

Tags: linux, kernel, version

My ubuntu server returns `Linux 3.13.0-63-generic` when I run `uname -rs`. From what I found in internet, `uname` is also a system call which can't be easily overridden when third party program run this system call from C++ for example.

Does anyone know if there is a way to spoof the return value, like by manipulating `/proc/sys/kernel/ostype` files? It will be even better if I can spoof it per process instance.

Comment: What does this have to do with Firefox? If your underlying problem has something to do with Firefox, ask a question about that problem; spoofing uname is unlikely to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are only limited ways in which `release` (`uname -r`) and `machine` (`uname -m`) can be customized per process using the [`personality()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html), all exposed through the [`setarch` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setarch.8.html), and `sysname` (`uname -r`) cannot be customized at all.

```
$ uname -rsm; setarch i386 --uname-2.6 --32bit uname -rsm
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64
Linux 2.6.56-4-amd64 i686
```

If you want to spoof uname in a different way and the program is dynamically linked, you can use `LD_PRELOAD` to override the `uname` function; see [Redirect a file descriptor before execution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211394/redirect-a-file-descriptor-before-execution/211459#211459) for an example of function overload through `LD_PRELOAD`. If the program is statically linked, you can use `ptrace` to spoof its system calls, but that requires fancier programming.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. The reason I want to override uname system call and added a firefox tag is because firefox flash plugin use this call in one of the functions and I want it to return a faked value. I don't know if flash plugin is statically or dynamically linked, but I want to hire a freelancer to do this job and want to understand what proggramming skills he should have. Do you think it will be easier to override flash plugin function that use uname instead of overridding system calls?

Comment: @offline15 Overriding a function call is definitely easier than overriding a system call. [I'm doubtful that changing what `uname` returns would solve whatever problem you're having with the Flash plugin though](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).