# Hide or mask directory for a process on OS-X

Tags: filesystems, mount, osx, fstab, chroot

Is there a method for a process (without root) to hide or mount over a path of the filesystem for itself? It shouldn't affect the actual filesystem, only the process itself and perhaps its children?

Bit of an odd use case, but I need to build something on an OSX build server as if it were a vanilla OSX machine. However unfortunately there are a few libs installed in `/usr/local/{include,lib}` which mess up the build and I don't have root on the machine. So I would like to temporary hide `/usr/local` while running `configure` and `make`.

I do not have write access to `/usr/local` so I cannot actually modify it.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to do this. It would be easier to tell `configure` to look in the correct places.

Comment: The problem is mostly preventing `make` from linking to libs in `/usr/local/lib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no direct way to do this.  You can use `chflags hidden` to hide things from the *Finder*, but that doesn't affect the command-line.

The solution would depend on the configure script.  It ***may*** simply look along `PATH` to notice the `/usr/local`, but more likely it will have a hardcoded list of directories to look at — including `/usr/local`.  To work around the former (`PATH`-based), you could adjust your path.  For the latter, the only thing that works is to modify the `configure` script.

The reason why you'll see hardcoded lists is that add-ons may not use the same search paths as the rest of the system.  For instance, the various BSD ports may use `/usr/pkg`, `/usr/local`, etc., and **partly** rely upon the packagers to set these pathnames in their build-scripts.  But programs that are not built as part of the ports system have to look for things in those places, to build with little user attention.

If you want to override the default search path for OSX, start with the `ld` manual page, which says

> ***Search paths***
>   **`ld`** maintains a list of directories to search for a library or framework
>   to use.  The **default** library search path is **`/usr/lib`** then **`/usr/local/lib`**.
>   The **`-L`** option will add a new library search path.  The default framework
>   search path is **`/Library/Frameworks`** then **`/System/Library/Frameworks`**.
>   (Note: previously, **`/Network/Library/Frameworks`** was at the end of the
>   default path.  If you need that functionality, you need to explicitly add
>   **`-F/Network/Library/Frameworks`**).  The **`-F`** option will add a new framework
>   search path.  The **`-Z`** option will **remove** the standard search paths.  The
>   **`-syslibroot`** option will prepend a prefix to all search paths.

and you can pass options to `ld` by prefixing them with `-Wl` (and using a comma where a space is needed).  For your purpose, you would write a script which

- uses `-Z` to remove the search paths, and
- add back the parts you need using `-L`

The `clang` option `-v` shows the details of the *compiler* front-end, and passing `-v` to `ld`, e.g., using `-Wl,-v` shows the *linker's* details.

Something like this, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh
clang -Wl,-Z -L/usr/lib -F/Library/Frameworks -F/System/Library/Frameworks "$@"
```

It is not documented in the `clang` manual, but a quick check shows that it would pass a plain `-Z` option to the linker.  On the other hand, `clang` does document options (mainly for gcc-compatibility) which suppress its searches of different categories of include-directories:

```
   -nostdinc
          Do not  search  the  standard  system  directories  or  compiler
          builtin directories for include files.

   -nostdlibinc
          Do not search the standard system directories for include files,
          but do search compiler builtin include directories.

   -nobuiltininc
          Do not search clang's builtin directory for include files.
```

It does not have an option for showing the search-path for include files, but you can infer that by running the preprocessor.

Once you've gotten the script working, then running the `configure` script, you would set `CC` to that script's name, e.g.,

```
./configure CC=cc-system
```

I've been doing this a while, but haven't needed this particular combination (see [Compiler wrappers](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#compiler_wrappers)).

Comment: Maybe `LDFLAGS="-Z -L/usr/lib -F/Library/Frameworks -F/System/Library/Frameworks"` will work...

Comment: What would be the equivalent of `-Z` to make `clang` remove `-I/usr/local/include` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the processes are cooperating (i.e. they don't deliberately try to work around the hiding) and that they're dynamically linked executable, you can use [`DYLD_PRELOAD`](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/) (that's the OSX name, most other Unix variants call it `LD_PRELOAD`) to load a library that wraps around file lookup functions and fakes some results.

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211394/redirect-a-file-descriptor-before-execution/211459#211459) is a code example that does approximately what you want. Depending on how the programs you run access the files you don't want them to see, you may have to override other functions, possibly `open` or `access`.

Comment: The only libraries I have in `/usr/local/lib` are *static*.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: Your suggestion wouldn't work on my OSX machine.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I don't see why not. The point is to prevent the build system from seeing the libraries in `/usr/local/lib`. It doesn't matter what type of files these are.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want to actually hide certain directories, you just want to make sure your `configure` script doesn't find certain files in that directory.

The easiest way to accomplish that is probably to open `configure.ac` in an editor and edit it so that it doesn't search for include files or libraries in `/usr/local`, and then regenerate the `configure` script. Alternatively, you could also edit `configure` directly, since it's just a shell script after all. However, that will be somewhat more complicated, since the script is generated.

Comment: The `configure` step actually succeeds, the problem is when `make` invokes the linker. clang always seems to prefer whatever is in `/usr/local/lib` even if you give it another `-L/some/path`.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, I got that. But the configure script configures the build, and it is then based upon that configuration that make decides what to do. So if you tell configure not to look at certain directories, then make should ignore them. Of course, it all depends on what software you're actually trying to build...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what library the build is picking up and how the `configure` script is set up, you might be able to disable its use by telling `configure` not to use that "external package" that provided the library, or to look for it at another path.

The way to do that with `configure` is usually to say either

```
$ ./configure --without-PACKAGE
```

to disable the use of the package, or,

```
$ ./configure --with-PACKAGE=PATH
```

to point to another path where it's installed, where `PACKAGE` is the "external package" that provides the library, and `PATH` is the prefix path where the package was installed.

Another solution would be to set up a virtual machine with the same configuration as the target machine and build there.